# Как правильно послать запрос на чтение не через POST?

Tags: post, запрос, get, любой-язык

В раздичных источниках по методам HTTP запроса написано:

> Метод GET запрашивает представление ресурса. Запросы с использованием
> этого метода могут только извлекать данные.
>
> POST используется для
> отправки сущностей к определённому ресурсу. Часто вызывает изменение
> состояния или какие-то побочные эффекты на сервере.

Есть ресурс, который на основе текста может выдать результат в какой книге или статье этот текст встречается. Например пользователь вводит какую-то цитату, происходит поиск и отображается, что это книга "Война и мир", том 2. Т.к. это запрос на получение данных, то по логике, нужно использовать метод `GET`.

Однако пользователь может вбить очень длинный текст, который превышает 2048 (ограничение `GET` запроса, особенно если это мультибайтовые строки, как я понимаю), то что делать в этом случае? В `GET` не вмещается, а `POST` не подходит под тип использования. Как быть?

Comment: Отправляйте POST. Никто не требует что бы POST обязательно что-то изменял.

Comment: @AlexeyTen а как же корректность работы с зарпосами?)И тогда не ясно как разделять запросы, в том плане: если это запрос на изменение или параметр запроса слишком велик - то можно пост?)

Comment: Это всё просто рекомендации. От них можно отступать при необходимости и понимании зачем.